# Azure Web App Deploy. Transforming the webconfig

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I am trying to chance some appsettings and the ConnectionString of an application in a certain slot in my Azure Web App.

When I try to change the config via the Application Settings on Azure portal, nothing happens.

So I found this post:

> http://brian.vallelunga.com/blog/chaining-azure-web-config-transforms-when-deploying-from-source-control

Ok, I done what the tutorial tells me to do and I got success on some deploys (I am using Kudu for auto deploy from GitHub).

But suddenly (without any change of config) the deploys are using the Release transform, instead of the dev one.

Via `Kudu` console, I saw in deployment folder, in some moment `Kudu` transformed my web.config in right one, and after transforms it again into the release version.
Someone have any idea what I can do?

Oh. My solution have more than one web project. I am using the `"Project"` Key on Azure application config page and that one works.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, found the answer.
For some strange reason, the value of the parameter `SCM_BUILD_ARGS` changed from `/p:Environment=Staging` to `-p:Configuration=Debug`.

I just passed that value on Azure app settings and voil! It's working now :)